# Xtext "15 Minutes Tutorial" - Can't generate dmodel file

Tags: xtext, emf

I'm setting up a new Xtext project and I wanna generate an EMF presentation. To Do that, I followed this tutorial: https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html?fbclid=IwAR1slqIR_-lZvZNGH2ZRTio9Cnef01ASkUFBmN52sVW5EQpGHat0eMpNSoU

The 3 first steps are working fine.However, I had a problem with the 4th step: Run the Generated Eclipse Plug-in.

I can't figure about how should I generate the mymodel.dmodel file.

Any help please !

Comment: am not sure what your problem is. what do you mean by generate. you create it using the file new  dialog

Comment: I need to create that file mymodel.dmodel, because it will be used in the next steps. But I don't know how!
 As it is mentioned in the tutorial, after  Run As → Eclipse Application and create a new project  File → New → Project… → Java Project. After that, should I create the mymodel.dmodel manually by myself or it will be generated automatically when I did Run As → Generate Xtext Artifacts.

Comment: no you need to do File -> New -> File to create it manually